# Why J2EE 1.4 and Java EE 5 naming?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, versioning

Can anybody explain why the difference in naming of two version of Java Enterprise Edition.  J2EE 1.4 and next version is Java EE 5.

What would be reason behind this?

Comment: In regard to the numbering *"Keeping up with the Joneses"*.  This is not an official answer you will get from Oracle, but where many other plug-ins would go for whole number upgrades, Sun's naming system was increasing by values of 0.1.  It creates the impression (to the unwashed masses) that Java is not advancing as quickly.

Comment: @AndrewThompson that maybe holds for the version number, but there's also the removal of the 2. In that case, the 2 simply made no sense. It was as if the language was called "java2" instead of "java", where the 2 was not related to a version anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Oracle [website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/namechange-140185.html):

> Sun Microsystems simplified the platform name in 2006 to better reflect the level of maturity, stability, scalability, and security built into the Java platform. Sun dropped the "2" from the name and deleted the "dot number" (the number following the period). Any updates to Java platforms will simply be noted as updates rather than adding a "dot number" at the end of the platform name.

The above article relates to Java SE, but the same applies for Java EE, see [here](http://www.java.com/en/about/javanaming.jsp) for more information.